# Compile error for cve-2017-1000253 proof of concept

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-errors, centos7, exploit

I am trying to compile an exploit to pentest on a CentOS 7 virtual machine. Here is the code I am trying to compile: [`cve-2017-1000253.c`](https://www.qualys.com/2017/09/26/linux-pie-cve-2017-1000253/cve-2017-1000253.c). I get this error when I try to compile it.

[image: error]

I know that there is no rootshell.h to create it but the website did not provide it.Is the rootshell.h in the code that i need to create a new file with that code inside?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact error. Links to code and images on other sites is usually not acceptable. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and  Also see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/608639).

Answer (score 1):

Please read the comment after the copyright header in `cve-2017-1000253.c`.  It contains a shell script, with the following commands at the end:

```
gcc -fpic -shared -nostartfiles -Os -s -o rootshell rootshell.c
xxd -i rootshell > rootshell.h
```

Running this shell script will produce the required `rootshell.h` file.